# 405 (Método no permitido) Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

Hola tengo un inconeniente con mi formulario ajax me podrian ayuda, cuando intento enviar me tira error 405 en el sumbit

estas son mis rutas, esto aprendiendo ajax, asi que no se si implmente bien mis

```
 Route::get('/home', 'Web\EmailController@form');
    Route::post('/store_customer', 'Web\EmailController@store');
```

rutas[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este seria mi formulario

```
 {{-- alerta de lmensaje id alert box muestra el mensaje si se envio con exito la peticion --}}
                        <div id="alert_box" class="alert alert-success" style="display:none"></div>
                    <form action=""  method="GET" id="myForm" >
                            {{-- id myform con metodo post --}}

                        @csrf
                        {{-- dos input uno de tipo submit y otro type email --}}
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><input type="submit"  id="ajaxSubmit" value="Suscribite">

                    </form>
```

Comment: Tu código como texto por favor

Comment: cambiar la linea donde hace el metodo de ajax a post method:'get' lo tiene que cambiar por method:'post' y añadir el toke al enviar el formulario  en el data _token:$('input[name=_token]').val()

Answer (score 0):

voy a dejar un ejemplo de envio de datos con ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/store_customer',
    data: {

    'id': $('#id_mass').val(),
    'nombre': $('#nombre_mass').val(),
    'created_at': $('#created_at_mass').val(),
    'updated_at': $('#updated_at_mass').val(),
    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
        //toastr.error('Error de operación!', 'No se pudo Añadir los datos<br>', {timeOut: 5000});
    },
    success: function(data) { 
        if ((data.errors)) {

        } else {

        }
    },
});
```

en laravel tiene un nivel de seguridad por URL por el cual solo se permita realiza peticiones si la URL esta inscrita

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing

```
Route::get($uri, $callback);
Route::post($uri, $callback);
Route::put($uri, $callback);
Route::patch($uri, $callback);
Route::delete($uri, $callback);
Route::options($uri, $callback);
```

si envia una peticion por post debe incluir **Request $request**

```
 //archivo desde el controlador   
 public function store(Request $request, $id){
    $CategoriaParqueadero=true;
    return response()->json($CategoriaParqueadero);
 }
```

y en el archivo web.php

```
Route::post('/store_customer', 'Web\EmailController@store');
```

el error es el siguiente:

```
type: 'GET',=>Route::post() == ERROR
type: 'POST',=>Route::post() == TRUE
```